# Remove duplicate rows in df which contains tibbles in one column; explicitly not using dplyr

Tags: r, duplicates, data.table, tibble

I would like to remove all duplicate rows from a dataframe which contains tibbles in one column without using the package dplyr. As I am new to tibbles and handling them, I need your help.

```
library(tibble)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

#create tibbles
tibble_inst <- tibble(id = c("ABC1234", "DEF123", "GHI12"),
                      name = c("abc inst", "def inst", "ghi inst")
)
tibble_aag1 <- tibble(id = c("AA1111", "AA2222"),
                      name = c("AA", "AB")
)
tibble_aag2 <- tibble(id = c("ABC1234", "DEF123", "GHI12"),
                      name = c("abc inst", "def inst", "ghi inst")
)

# create col with tibble
matched = list(tibble_aag1, NULL, tibble_inst, tibble_inst, tibble_inst, 
               tibble_aag1, tibble_aag2, NULL, NULL, tibble_inst)

# create df
dt <- data.table(
  word = c("A AG", "WIL", "Inst", "Inst", "Inst", 
           "A AG", "A AG", "Inst", "WIL", "Inst"),
  entity = c("ORG", "ORG", "ORG", "ORG", "ORG", "ORG", "ORG", "ORG", "ORG", "ORG"),
  page_num = c(1,2,4,4,4,1,4,2,0,1))
dt$matched <- matched
dt
```

The code solution using dplyr would look like this:

```
dt1 <- dt %>% distinct(word, page_num, matched)
dt1
```

This does not work and I do not know to handle the error message:

```
cols <- c("word", "page_num", "matched")
dt2 <- dt[!duplicated(dt[cols]), cols, drop = FALSE]
Error: When i is a data.table (or character vector), the columns 
to join by must be specified using 'on=' argument (see ?data.table), by
 keying x (i.e. sorted, and, marked as sorted, see ?setkey), or by 
sharing column names between x and i (i.e., a natural join). Keyed 
joins might have further speed benefits on very large data due to x 
being sorted in RAM.
```

The result I expect should look like this:

```
# A tibble: 7 × 3
  word  page_num matched         
  <chr>    <dbl> <list>          
1 A AG         1 <tibble [2 × 2]>
2 WIL          2 <NULL>          
3 Inst         4 <tibble [3 × 2]>
4 A AG         4 <tibble [3 × 2]>
5 Inst         2 <NULL>          
6 WIL          0 <NULL>          
7 Inst         1 <tibble [3 × 2]>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `duplicated` you could do:

```r
cols <- c("word", "page_num", "matched")
dt2 <- dt[!duplicated(dt[cols]), cols, drop = FALSE]

dt2
#> # A tibble: 7 × 3
#>   word  page_num matched         
#>   <chr>    <dbl> <list>          
#> 1 A AG         1 <tibble [2 × 2]>
#> 2 WIL          2 <NULL>          
#> 3 Inst         4 <tibble [3 × 2]>
#> 4 A AG         4 <tibble [3 × 2]>
#> 5 Inst         2 <NULL>          
#> 6 WIL          0 <NULL>          
#> 7 Inst         1 <tibble [3 × 2]>

library(dplyr)

dt1 <- dt %>% distinct(word, page_num, matched)

identical(dt1, dt2)
#> [1] TRUE
```

**UPDATE** First. IMHO it is no good practice to alter a question in a way which makes the answers which solved the original question useless. In these case I would suggest to post a new question.

Be it as it is. The issue is that your `dt` object is now a `data.table` object. This means that `dt[cols]` will not work. Instead we have to do e.g. `dt[,..cols]` so select columns given as a character vector. However, even after fixing that we get an error

> Column 3 passed to [f]order is type 'list', not yet supported.

I also tried with `unique(dt[, ..cols])` and `dtplyr` but always get the same issue. Not an expert in using `data.table` but from the error message I would guess that the `duplicated` method for `data.table` does not work with `list` columns. But I might be wrong.

But a fix would be to use the default `duplicated.data.frame` method:

```r
library(data.table)

cols <- c("word", "page_num", "matched")

dt[!duplicated.data.frame(dt[, ..cols]), ..cols, drop = FALSE]
#>    word page_num       matched
#> 1: A AG        1 <tbl_df[2x2]>
#> 2:  WIL        2              
#> 3: Inst        4 <tbl_df[3x2]>
#> 4: A AG        4 <tbl_df[3x2]>
#> 5: Inst        2              
#> 6:  WIL        0              
#> 7: Inst        1 <tbl_df[3x2]>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I had to update the data frame example as I did not reproduce my example and error message correctly. Now the data frame is ready, and when using your solution it gives me the above error message.

Comment: Just made an update offering a fix for the altered setup.